# GIT comment replacement and injection

Tags: git, version-control, pvcs

Can GIT do injection/token replacement at the point of code checkin?

PVCS did something for firm XYZ by injecting/token replacement for values.  Case in point:

If we have code that looked like this:

```
/* $Workfile:$
* Created By: [Developer Name HERE]
* Created On: [Date created in mm/dd/ccyy format, HERE]
*
* Last Revision:
* $Revision:$
* $Date:$
* $Author:$
*
* All rights reserved.
*

*/  

            [INSERT MY AMAZING CODE HERE]

/*
$Log:$
*/
```

PVCS would turn it into the following, Yellow highlights would be updates to the file and Green highlights are my comments.

```
/* $Workfile:  Constants.java  $   (Filename injected)
* Created By: [Developer Name HERE]
* Created On: [Date created in mm/dd/ccyy format, HERE]
*
* Last Revision:
* $Revision:   1.0  $
* $Date:   Jun 26 2015 06:50:52  $
* $Author:   Jsmith  $
*
* All rights reserved.
*
*/    

/*
$Log:   M:/PVCS/xxx Project Database/archives/xx/EJB/src/com/xxxxcommon/Constants.java-arc  $
//    Rev 1.0   Aug 14 2009 18:10:30   jsmith
// Initial revision.   (Comment I used at point of code check-in)
*/
```

Can we do that if so what do we need to change to make sure we can do it consistently across all of the source code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` does support some limited variable expansion functions, although they are not done at check-in time. In `git help gitattributes`, see the sections on `ident` and `export-subst`, as well as the `filter` options mentioned in VonC's answer. The `ident` expansion occurs on checkout, while the `export-subst` only occurs when using `git archive`. The `filter` option applies to both checkin and checkout paths, and can be much more general, but useful configuration of it takes a fair amount of work for anything that has different requirements for different sorts of files (e.g. C code vs shell scripts - different comment formats) or other complex requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)**, specifically a clean filter

[image: clean filter]

<sup>(image shown in "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

It can execute a script of your choice to a specific file or set of files [declared in a `.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_filter_code).

The .gitattributes is versioned and will be visible/used by all developers.

But the content filter must be activated by a git config directive.

```
git config filter.xxx.clean 'script'
```

And that is a *local* setting which needs to be repeated by all developers, so that might not be ideal.